# How are epiphytes symbiotic?

Tags: ecology, environment

I understand epiphytes are not parasitic. But how exactly are they helping the tree on which they grow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note that not all symbiotic relationships must be expressed in terms of a positive-negative (parasitism) or a positive-positive (mutualism) framework. I would guess that most tree epiphytes exist in a commensal framework with their host trees. That is, the epiphyte has a positive interaction (it gets somewhere to grow), and the host species has neither positive nor negative effects.

Comment: I didn't realise symbiotic relationship is superset of mutualism and parasitism!

Comment: @yathish the terminology in the ecological literature gets pretty malleable, but the Greek root basically means "living together" so can describe a range of relationships.